# I am building a Wordpress website with several hundred dynamically generated PHP pages. What would be the recommended way to do this?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, custom-wordpress-pages

My Wordpress website (gcsemathsworksheets.com) will consist of at least 300-400 randomly generated math worksheets coded in PHP. At the moment I am using a shortcode plugin (PHP-code-for-posts) to insert PHP code, but the plugin hasn't been updated for months and looks like it has been removed from wordpress.org.

My options appear to be:

1. Use a different PHP shortcode plugin
2. Use custom templates (a new template for each worksheet) as mentioned at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73440/how-to-add-a-php-custom-page-to-wordpress?rq=1

Are there other options? What would be the recommended method (in terms of best practices/performance/security etc.)?

Thank-you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Security:**

Code which evaluates other code (as your plugin does) is considered to be a greater security risk; even authors of million user plus plugins can get it wrong https://blog.sucuri.net/2013/05/w3-total-cache-and-wp-super-cache-vulnerability-being-targeted-in-the-wild.html

You have to sanitize input with either method; so using your own page template is likely a safer option.

**Performance:**

Performance will vary from plugin to plugin dependent on how well designed. A page template with your code is likely to perform better than your code via a 3rd party plugin, but the difference may not be noticeable.

Your description indicates *page* caching won't be possible. However, under PHP 7 (possibly even on 5.5+) performance is enhanced by using opcache (cached "compiled" copies of your site's scripts) and your site would benefit from this. **However code provided via your plugin (and probably its equivalents) is evaled on the fly so and won't be opcached**.

I have a single custom page that provides different dynamic content for 2000 different "URL" requests; however these only involve 2 parameters (from one query variable) e.g. WP re-write rules are set to change a request for `http://example.com/country/egypt/money` into `custpage/?queryvar='egypt/money'` for delivery of content. I can provide a rewrite example if needed.

Output of your pages may be more complex and depend on many different variables. If so it may be better for performance and simplicity to create separate custom pages to handle the different type of math questions.

**Longer term, maintenance and expansion.**

Again a custom template is the way to go.  Once over your learning curve the knowledge will make it easier for you to enhance and expand your current Wordpress site and others you may wish to set up.

Comment: You have convinced me to go with custom templates. To be specific, it looks like I need Custom Page Templates for Specific Pages, copying the existing page.php file and renaming it with the page’s slug or ID:
page-{slug}.php or page-{ID}.php   https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-a-custom-page-template-for-one-specific-page

Answer (score 1):

i think best practice is to pass the "random" variables.
And save them to a Database with an id. So if you need the template u generate it in livetime

> GET /worksheet/generate/[ID]

---

MfG R0b1ns